# Android Videoview Set Width,Height,X and Y

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, android-layout

my screen android phone width=888 height=672

i want to make videoview with X=670  and Y=250

(videoWidth=500 , videoHeight=200 ,videoX=670 , videoY=250)

i was try with code below

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        videoWidth, videoHeight, videoX, videoY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

but video show all and X and Y moving to left,so X and Y not Fiks, how i can make videoview with X and Y Fiks,i want make it with programmatically no xml, Thank you

like a link my picture [exampe image screen and videoview](https://brightofjava.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dsc_0498.jpg)

i was try this

i try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/playersurface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
```

but is same, cannot show x -37

Comment: I think image you are referring is not present here.Please give the link to that image .

Comment: https://brightofjava.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dsc_0498.jpg this link my image,please help

Comment: if you use surface view instead of  video view you can get cropped view.